# Regex to match if not followed by a character?

Tags: regex

I would like a regex that matches "Public Enter" when it is not followed by a ','.

For the below, I would like to match all rows except the last one.

```
FINE: 4E565DC7 Public Enter: "abasadf"
FINE: 4E565DC7 Public Enter: "xsdafsdf"
FINE: 4E565DC7 Public Enter: 
FINE: 4E565DC7 Public Enter: 
FINE: 1F9797F Public Enter: 
FINE: 1263259 Public Enter: 2
FINE: 1263259 Public Enter: 1, 0
```

Comment: Neither question nor desired result match each other.

Comment: my mistake, I meant ',' instead of 'c'. Edited question.

Comment: Now there is another problem... what have you tried?

Comment: `/Public Enter(?!.*,)/`

Comment: @revo @anubhava thanks, I was close... I had tried: `Public Enter(?!,)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matches such rows

`(?m)^(?=.*Public Enter(?!.*,)).*`